# Adding EventListener 'click' to asset

Tags: javascript, aframe

```js
let starting = -45, forward1 = 1, forward2 = 1, forward3 = 1;
let ball1;
let cannon1;
let ship;

window.onload = function() {
  ball1 = document.getElementById("ball1");
  cannon1 = document.getElementById("cannon1");

  cannon1.addEventListener("click",function(obj){
    ball1.fire = true;
  })
  update();
  
};

function update(){
  if(ball1.fire){
    starting += forward1;
    ball1.setAttribute("position", {x:-starting - 20, y:7, z:0})
  }
  if(starting >= 100){
    ball1.setAttribute("position", {x:0, y:7, z:50})
    starting = 0;
    ball1.fire = false;
  }

  setTimeout(update,10);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <body>
    <a-scene id="scene">

      //camera
      <a-camera rotation = "0 90 0" position = "0 5 0">
            <a-cursor></a-cursor>
      </a-camera>
      
      //other
      <a-sky src = "sky.jpg"></a-sky>
      <a-plane position = "2 0 -20"rotation = "-90 0 0"width ="5000" height = "5000" material = "src:ocean.jpg;repeat: 1 1"></a-plane>

      //3d models
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="ship" src="ship/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="cannon1" src="cannon/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      
      //ship
      <a-gltf-model src="#ship" position = "0 0 0" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-gltf-model>

      //cannons
      <a-gltf-model src="#cannon1" rotation = "0 0 0" position = "-4.7 4.1 2.2" scale="0.02 0.02 0.025"></a-gltf-model> 

      //balls
      <a-sphere id ="ball1" color="black" position = "-4.7 4.1 2.2" radius="0.3" rotation = "0 0 0"></a-sphere>

        //cannon 1
        <a-box position = "-2 6 -10" color="black" depth="2" height="2" width="2"></a-box>
        <a-box position = "2 6 -10" color="black" depth="2" height="2" width="2"></a-box>
        <a-box id = "fire1" position = "0 7 -12" color="brown" depth="7" height="2" width="2"></a-box>
        <a-box id ="myBox1" position = "0 7 -10" color="red" rotation = "0 0 0" ></a-box>   

    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

which just says if the user clicks on an object with the id of "cannon1" a ball shoots forward.

This exact code worked with an a  with the id of "cannon1", but when I import a 3d model of a cannon and assign it "cannon1", the code doesn't seem to work

Comment: Can you update your answer to show how you load the asset, getElementById will return tags with a matching id property, if you don't load it with this ID(in html) it won't work.

Comment: show your html, then we could figure what is wrong

Comment: let me update it

Comment: is that supposed to be attached to an asset-item?  The event listener appears to be on the wrong object?  And where's the cursor.  Did click work before?

Comment: the main goal is, when you click on the cannon model, the asset, it "fires" causing the ball to move forward

Comment: right, I'm saying that you didn't define cursor attributes https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.html#events and that your event listeners are attached to a-assets (which only emit loaded events) rather than the actual entities

Answer (score 0):

```
<a-gltf-model id="shipEntity" src="#ship" position = "0 0 0" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-gltf-model>
```

You need to attach the click event listener to the entity, not the asset reference.

```
shipEntity.addEventListener('click',()=>ball1.fire=true);
```

`<a-cursor>` is for gaze-based interactions.  Read: https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/introduction/interactions-and-controllers.html#events

Added `rayOrigin: mouse` onto the scene to use mouse click based events.  Most of your positioning is off, so I've adjusted the demo to just show that this works.  You'll have to adjust it to whatever it is you are doing.  The brown box is clickable.

```js
let starting = -45, forward1 = 1, forward2 = 1, forward3 = 1;
let ball1;
let cannon1;
let ship;

window.onload = function() {
  ball1 = document.getElementById("ball1");
  cannon = document.getElementById("cannon-entity");

  cannon.addEventListener("click",function(obj){
    ball1.fire = true;
  })
  update();
  
};

function update(){
  if(ball1.fire){
    starting += forward1;
    ball1.setAttribute("position", {x:-starting - 20, y:7, z:0})
  }
  if(starting >= 100){
    ball1.setAttribute("position", {x:0, y:7, z:50})
    starting = 0;
    ball1.fire = false;
  }

  setTimeout(update,10);
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <a-scene id="scene" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">

      //camera
      <a-camera rotation = "0 90 0" position = "0 0 20">
      </a-camera>
      
      //other
      <a-sky src = "sky.jpg"></a-sky>
      <a-plane position = "2 0 -20"rotation = "-90 0 0"width ="5000" height = "5000" material = "src:ocean.jpg;repeat: 1 1"></a-plane>
<
      //3d models
      <a-assets>
        <a-asset-item id="ship" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/9176d098/2.0/Duck/glTF/Duck.gltf" x="ship/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
        <a-asset-item id="cannon1" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/AnimatedCube/glTF/AnimatedCube.gltf" x="cannon/scene.gltf"></a-asset-item>
      </a-assets>
      
      //ship
      <a-gltf-model id="ship-entity" src="#ship" position = "0 0 0" scale="0.5 0.5 0.5"></a-gltf-model>

      //cannons
      <a-gltf-model id="cannon-entity" src="#cannon1" rotation = "0 0 0" position = "0 0 0" scale="1 1 1"></a-gltf-model> 

      //balls
      <a-sphere id ="ball1" color="black" position = "-4.7 4.1 2.2" radius="0.3" rotation = "0 0 0"></a-sphere>

        //cannon 1
        <a-box position = "-2 6 -10" color="black" depth="2" height="2" width="2"></a-box>
        <a-box position = "2 6 -10" color="black" depth="2" height="2" width="2"></a-box>
        <a-box id = "fire1" position = "0 7 -12" color="brown" depth="7" height="2" width="2"></a-box>
        <a-box id ="myBox1" position = "0 7 -10" color="red" rotation = "0 0 0" ></a-box>   

    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```